# Can I get (at least public) emails of the _non_-authenticated user with Github API?

Tags: github-api

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/emails?apiVersion=2022-11-28#about-email-administration says

> If a request URL does not include a {username} parameter then the response will be for the signed-in user (and you must pass authentication information with your request). Additional private information, such as whether a user has two-factor authentication enabled, is included when authenticated through OAuth with the user scope.

But I don't see a `{username}` parameter in any of the listed endpoints. Is the only email I can get for another user the main one from [GET
/users/{username}](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-user)?